# $_SESSION, не определяется переменная.

Tags: php, javascript

Здарвствуйте.
Есть `index.php`, в нем функция `javascript`.

```
$(function() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'fileSizeLimit' : '150000',
        'formData'     : {
            'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
            'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
        },
        //'fileSizeLimit' : '150000KB',
        'swf'      : 'engine/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : 'engine/uploadify.php'
    });
});
```

В данном файле есть задается `$_SESSION['user']=11;`
В файле `uploadify.php` есть вызов `$user=$_SESSION['user'];`
Однако при срабатывании данной функции `$user=0`.
Не могу понять почему. В `index.php` если прописать `$user=$_SESSION['user'];`, значение 11.
В опере и фаерфоксе такая беда.
Все работает только в Хроме.

Comment: @votanko, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 2):

А вызов session_start() перед обращением к массиву $_SESSION присутствует в коде?

```
if (!isset($_SESSION))
  session_start();
```

Comment: В самом начале страницы.
<?php
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['user'];//текущий айди пользователя

Comment: Есть еще небольшое уточнение, не работает это в фаерфоксе.
Однако в хроме все прекрасно отрабатывает.

Comment: Проблема какая то с яваскриптом мб?

Comment: Проблема с JS? Вряд ли.

Проверьте, задаётся ли в FireFox значение идентификатора сессии в COOKIE.

Приведите полный код обоих файлов (index.php и uploadify.php), возможно, найдутся ошибки.

Comment: Очень много кода((.  
Здесь я просто написал про 2 файла для более хорошего понимания.  
На самом деле дело обстоит так.  
Есть самый начальный файл index2.php, в него идет импорт  
`require_once "engine/add_request.php";`    
в файл add_request.php уже в свою очередь идет файл  
`require_once "example1.php";`  

В нем как раз эта функция описанная выше.  
Сессия задается в index.php

Comment: Переменная сессии видна везде, кроме uploadify.php.  
В самом uploadify.php могу создавать переменные сессии, и они видны в этом файле.

Comment: Проверьте, задаётся ли в FireFox значение идентификатора сессии в COOKIE.  
А как это можно проверить?  
Вроде погуглил, но ничего не нашел.

Comment: Проверить можно с помощью плагина FireBug. У него есть вкладка Cookies, где будет список активных записей для текущей страницы. Среди них надо искать индентификатор сессии, который, как правило, называется PHPSESSID.

Comment: http://getfirebug.com/